# preg_match username validation regex allows > and < despite those characters not being whitelisted

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this relatively simple regex for usernames

```
// Enforce that username has to be 3-100 characters, alphanumeric, and first character a letter.
// Possibility without begin/end characters and i: [a-z][a-z0-9@.+-_]{2,100}
// Allow for simple email usernames in the future...
return !!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9@.+-_]{2,100}$#', trim($username));
```

Which, unfortunately, allows these XSS-ready test strings:

```
'angle<bracket',
'angle>bracket',
'html<script>inside',
```

And I have no idea why since they already should explicitly be disallowed by the regex.

Here is a running test case:

http://ideone.com/od7dj

Anyone know why angle brackets are being allowed by a regex that doesn't explicitly allow for them?  Am I supposed to escape one of those characters (.+-) as literals?

Comment: Use an explicit `(bool)` cast instead of `!!` - the double-not is bad practice as it's not always immediately obvious what it is there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of this: `[+-_]`

You are including all chars between '+' and '_', try changing the order to `[+_-]` (putting the dash at the end) or escape the dash.

Comment: That does explain -why- those characters were causing problems, because it was acting as a range, thanks.  In the future I'll just escape dashes when I'm using them literally.

Answer (score 6):

`+-_` is your problem. You need to escape the `-` in a character class or move it to the end or beginning of the class.

For example:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9@.+_-]{2,100}\z/i
```