# Python re: why does [,-_] match "="?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm observing the following behaviour in python 2.7.5:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'[,-_]', '=') # This matches
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f24d4981308>
>>> re.match(r'[-,_]', '=') # This doesn't match
>>> re.match(r'[-_,]', '=') # Nor does this
```

Can someone explain what I'm seeing here? I can't seem to find anything about `,-_` being special in python regexes (or raw strings for that matter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match username validation regex allows > and < despite those characters not being whitelisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996951/preg-match-username-validation-regex-allows-and-despite-those-characters-not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the same idiom as in `[A-Z]` which matches everything from A to Z. In this case, it will match everything from `,` (ASCII #44) to `_` (ASCII #95), which includes `=` (ASCII #61).

See the [full ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Because the hyphen (`-`) defines a range and `=` is between `,` and `_` in the ASCII table. You need to escape it so that the regex engine treats it as a literal hyphen, like so `r'[,\-_]'`. Raw strings are skipped by the interpreter, but not treated as literals from the regex engine that's why you need to escape special characters.

Comment: You can also just make the hyphen the first or last character in the character class, so it can't possibly indicate a range; then it is taken literally.